# DataGridViewRow Wrong Cell Index

Tags: c#, datagridviewrow

i've got a problem while trying to get some values through the DataGridViewRow.
the problem is my cell index is 7 and when i try to get the data from the cell using this code:

```
 foreach (DataGridViewRow r in this.mydatagrid.Rows)
        {
            if (Convert.ToBoolean(r.Cells[0].Value) == true)
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cc = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)r.Cells[7];
                cc.Value = toolStripComboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
                edit_subject(Convert.ToInt32(r.Cells[1].Value), r.Cells[7].Value.ToString());
            }
```

an Exception Error Comes Saying That Cells[7] is OutOfIndex .
 so i've tried to change the cell index from 7 to 5 and it's worked 
sometimes , and sometimes no .

please i need explain because it's really weird.

Comment: It starts counting at 0.  So index 7 is the 8th cell.  There aren't 8 cells in your data grid apparently.

Comment: It will help if you set a breakpoint on your `edit_subject` line, and see what `r.Cells[1].Value` is equal to.  This will help you understand the ordering of your cells.  As @phpmeh said, you probably don't have a cell at index 7 if there are only 7 values in your row then the highest cell index will be 6.

Comment: Show us the markup of your control, then we would see if actually there are 7 cells

Comment: @phpmeh i've tried to debug in so many ways , it's 7 cells starting by the 0 of course . 

my datagrid contains 8  cells , 7 are textboxcell and the last is comboboxcell.

when i said it's worked by changing the index to 5 that's mean there's something wrong with the cells indexing because the correct index for the comboboxcell is 7 . but in somehow it became 5.
note: i've used same cells with correct index in same program but different code and it's working fine

i've checked the value , whenever it's worked i got the right value
when ever it didn't i got the wrong value from the wrong cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i found a solution, the problem caused because my SQL Syntax (The Datagrid Datasource) has different order than the datagridview columns, 
i didn't get it because the datagrid autofill has been disabled . 
and i've set the DataPropertyName for each column manually.

anyway , thanks for your response.